# SBCL: Deploying Hunchentoot application as executable

Tags: common-lisp, executable, sbcl, hunchentoot

I started playing with SBCL Common Lisp and want to develop a small web application using Hunchentoot. For easy deployment I planned to save everything in a binary using sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die as I can live with the big output size.

For the executable you need to supply a toplevel function. The problem is that the program exits when the toplevel function returns. I tried to start Hunchentoot from the executable, but the program ended after two seconds.

How can I wait until Hunchentoot was shut down (from inside a request) before stopping the program? Can I do something like join the Hunchentoot acceptor thread? Or can I even include the REPL into the executable to be able to do live debugging?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to deploy your app? I am in the same position now. I wrote a quick app and would like to deploy it. What tools did you use?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm taking notes on that on [lisp-journey/web-dev#deployment](https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/web-dev/#deployment). Just can't say for sure since I couldn't run my app yet because of an sbcl error.

Comment: @Ehvince great! I will keep my eye on it. By the way, I would be curious to get a list of Lisp resources that you have found useful on your Lisp journey. Suggestions for books, online articles, etc.

Comment: The resources I found really useful are basically in the Good Resources tab, + CL Recipes by E. Weitz (highly recommended to have a large overview of practical things. Lacks modern tools and libraries though) + reading sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(ql:quickload :hunchentoot)
(use-package :hunchentoot)

(defun main ()
  (hunchentoot:start-server :port 8082)
  (sb-thread:join-thread (find-if
                          (lambda (th)
                            (string= (sb-thread:thread-name th) "hunchentoot-listener-1"))
                          (sb-thread:list-all-threads))))
```

No explicit code is required to give you access to a REPL if you keep a terminal open (perhaps via GNU Screen). Send Ctrl+C to the terminal to break into the debugger.

Comment: It seems like I am working with a newer version of Hunchentoot. I had to use (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 8080) and the thread was called "hunchentoot-listener-*:8080". Works like a charm.

Comment: how about ```(find-if
   (lambda (th)
     (search "hunchentoot-listener" (sb-thread:thread-name th)))
   (sb-thread:list-all-threads))``` for the ```find-if``` part

Comment: or simply use `--eval "(loop do (sleep 86400))"` in function `main`

Comment: @PeterSlotko yeah, that seems better, because for me, it's not called `hunchentoot-listener-1` but instead called `hunchentoot-listener-*:4242`, so using `search` instead of `string=` makes that piece of this answer less brittle.  Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
;;; I simply use sleep to yield the main thread.
;;; To start the server while developing I use
;;; start-server.  For deployment I use the main
;;; function.

(defun start-server ()
  (hunchentoot:start
    (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 8000)))

(defun main()
  (start-server)
  (sleep #xffffffff))
```

Comment: This might be the best answer, because joining threads can be subject to a race condition. Also `(sleep most-positive-fixnum)`.